# How to validate a check sum on a downloaded file?

Tags: eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [File checksum calculator for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/104355/file-checksum-calculator-for-windows)

I downloaded [image] eclipse but How can I validate the check sum? SHA1 on the image?

Comment: Related on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6943834/516290

Comment: `md5sum` for linux in MacOSx i use `md5`

Answer (score -1):

I upload files I download to virustotal.com  It checks them for virus's against a boatload of virus scanners, and gives me info like sha1, md5, etc.

Comment: Uploading a 130MB file somewhere else just to check the SHA1 sum seems a little overboard if you could just check it locally.

Comment: http://download.cnet.com/Marxio-File-Checksum-Verifier/3000-18514_4-10913355.html